# JavaFX - css doesn't work in my project, but can work in scene builder

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm learning to use Scene Builder.I have read some same question but I'm still so confused.

I write a `css` to set the background,this is my `css` code:

```
 @charset"UTF-8";
.bodybg{
    -fx-background-image: url('../background.jpg');
    -fx-background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```

When I preview my interface , it worked [image]

But when I use the `fxml` in my code,the background disapper.
[image]

This is my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        try {
            // Read file fxml and draw interface.
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/demo/StartUI.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);


            primaryStage.setTitle("test");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();


        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the CSS file in the project resources? Also, can you post your FXML file?

Comment: How do you include your css? Is it inline, within the .fxml file? Or is it within a <stylesheets> tag? How is your project structured? Do you read the fxml from the resources folder?

Comment: If your css and fxml aren't in the same directory then the relative path "../" could mess things up because it wouldn't find the image

Answer (score 0):

You may have not attached css sheet in fxml file. Now Edit your fxml file using any text editor (like notepad in windows).

Write this code just before children tag in your fxml file.

```
<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@your_css_file.css" />
</stylesheets>
```

this would look like :

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="233.0" prefWidth="481.0" 
styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ate.ChangePasswordController">

<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@your_css_file.css" />
</stylesheets>

   <children>

   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```